# Record update from outside the grid panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I work with ExtJS et Architect.

I have a toolbar outside my gridpanel and I have a button "update".

When I click on my grid for a selection and after I click on button "update" outside the grid, I have an error: it's impossible to use loadRecord because undefined.

My code :

```
ClickBtnParametresApplicatifsModifier: function(button, e, eOpts) {
    var evaluation_edit = 'var edit = Ext.create(\'ModuleGestion.view.'+ElementsParametresApplicatifs['formulaires'][activeTabParametresApplicatifs]+'\');';
    eval(evaluation_edit);  


    var evaluation_grid = 'var grid = this.getGrid'+ElementsParametresApplicatifs['designations'][activeTabParametresApplicatifs]+'()';
    eval(evaluation_grid);  

    record = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();

    if(record) {
        edit.down('form').loadRecord(record);
    }

},
```

How it's different of a function click and this parameters : button, e, eOpts and a function itemdblclick (on the grid) with the params store where this param exist?

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use eval like that. Just use string concatenation to create the class `var x = Ext.create('My.static.Bit' + dynamicStuff);`

Comment: it's true thanx, my problem is not solved

Comment: Would suggest you read the docs, specifically about the return type of `getSelection`.

Comment: this method work in my itemdblclick action controller but not in my button toolbar action (out the grid).... same in my delete action controler it's work

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if record has element? maybe using:

```
if(grid.getSelectionModel().hasSelection()){
   ...
}
```

Try too:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().getLastSelected()
```

Comment: The solution is to use index 0 of the record array : record[0]